# Jquery get checked select boxes from dropdown on click event

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am a bit new to jquery so sorry for asking.

I am using datatables and I created a bootstrap dropdown with the folowing code.

```
          { 'data': null, title: '', wrap: true, "render": function (item) { return '<div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i><span class="caret"></span></button><ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"><li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header">Detectives</li><input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Accountname"><li ><label><input type="checkbox" class="usa"> United States</label></li><li ><label><input type="checkbox" class="netherlands"> Netherlands</label></li><li ><label><input type="checkbox" class="Italy"> Italy</label></li><li ><label><input type="checkbox" class="china"> China</label></li><li ><label><input type="checkbox" class="gb"> Great Britain</label></li><li role="presentation" class="divider"></li><li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="searchtarget" href="#">Search</a></li></ul></div>' } },
```

What I want is to get the checked boxes when the user clicks the `class="searchtarget" href="#">Search</a>` link and post it to a php file. I am trying to get the checked property and testing the post in the folowing script. But the post is 0 even when checked.

```
<script>
$("#accountTable").on("change", "input[type='checkbox']",".checkbox-menu", function() {
   $(this).closest("li").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
});

$("#accountTable").on('click', '.allow-focus', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>



<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accountTable").on("click", ".searchtarget", function () { // notice the on function

            
            var SearchUSA = $(this).closest("li","input[type='checkbox']", ".usa").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
            var SearchNL = $(this).closest("li","input[type='checkbox']", ".netherlands").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
            var SearchItaly = $(this).closest("li","input[type='checkbox']", ".italy").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
            var SearchChina = $(this).closest("li","input[type='checkbox']", ".china").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
            var SearchGB = $(this).closest("li","input[type='checkbox']", ".gb").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testchecked.php",
                data: {
                    USA: SearchUSA,
                    NL: SearchNL,
                    Italy: SearchItaly,
                    China: SearchChina,
                    GB: SearchGB
                },

            });
            return true;
        });

    });
</script>
```

This is the post result when all is checked. It should all be 1. our when a user only selects a few only those need to be 1.

```
USA: 0
NL: 0
Italy: 0
China: 0
GB: 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Tried the answer of Kinglish. But get a error. `Uncaught ReferenceError: selected is not defined` I dont get it, it says selected is not defined. When I use `data: {selected: data}, });` it is but then I get the folowing result in my post. Is this right?

```
selected[selected][]: netherlands
selected[selected][]: Italy

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#accountTable").on("click", ".searchtarget", function () { // notice the on function
            $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
     .map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
           
     let data = {
      selected: $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
          
      }).get()
      
    }
  
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "testchecked.php", data: {selected: selected}, }); return true; });

    });
</script>
```

EDIT 2

Trying to get the typed value from the input box together with the selected boxes when the user uses the search link. But it wont show up.. What is wrong, can anyone explaing ?

```
 $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=text]').map(function() { return this.val; }).get();     
     let dataname = {
        findtarget: $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=text]').map(function() {
        return this.val;   
      }).get()
      
    }
var findtarget =  $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=text]').val();
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "testchecked.php", data: data,dataname,findtarget:findtarget }); return true; });
```

Comment: Anyone that can help? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplification. Just gather the checked values and send that off to the PHP. You can take that array and use it for the search. This line loop through the relevant checkboxes to get the values of the checked ones

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked')
     .map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accountTable").on("click", ".searchtarget", function() {
    let data = {
      selected: $(this).closest('ul').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function() {
        return this.value;
      }).get()
    }
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<table id='accountTable'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="dropdown"><button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Choose <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i><span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu checkbox-menu allow-focus" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="usa"> United States</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="netherlands"> Netherlands</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="italy"> Italy</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="china"> China</label></li>
          <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="gb"> Great Britain</label></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" class="searchtarget" href="#">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! No there is no special reason to use classes. I just dont know how to do this otherwise, as stated I am new. All I need are the checked propertys from the dropdown checkbos values and post them to a PHP. If there is a better solution to do this please tell !

Comment: Besides my above comment, how do I use these found values in my post script? I dont know how to implent that array to a post to have all them values post.

Comment: OK. I updated my answer and put values in your checkboxes. I would say just send that array of selected values off to PHP and let the PHP do what it will with it.

Comment: in PHP you would recieve the POST in my answer as $_POST['selected'] - which would come through as an array of selected countries.

Comment: I only show how to get the values here. Obviously, you will need to integrate this into your code and ajax functions

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. But this is not getting me my select data in PHP

Comment: $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testchecked.php",
                data: {selected},

            });
            return true;
        });

Comment: How Do I use that found data?

Comment: set the post variable `selected` to equal the array of selected items (also called `selected`) -- `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "testchecked.php", data: {selected: selected}, }); return true; });`

Comment: I do not get it. I get a error when I use your code.. Uncaught ReferenceError: selected is not defined. See the Edit in the answer for how I try it..

Comment: Ok, since you already created the variable `data` above the ajax function, change `data: {selected: selected}` into `data: data`

Comment: Thank you !, now I am trying to get the input text to.. but using the same way our my old way wont work. Can you explain why you did what you did? See Edit 2 in question